# When printing from Firefox I get strange symbols

Tags: firefox, pdf, printing

When I open [this](https://www.coaching-institutes.net/pdf/en/guidelines.pdf) pdf in Firefox its correctly shown, but when I print to my HP Officejet Pro 8600 from Firefox, the text looks partially very odd like this:

[image]

When I print it from Chrome, the outcome looks normal. Also when I tried it on another PC the outcome looks normal in Firefox and in Chrome.

The issue is only with Firefox on one specific PC. It happens to all PDF's. What can I do to find the issue?  I have the latest printer driver installed.

Answer (score 1):

Open "Options" from the Firefox menu. In the "General" section under "Language and Appearance", click the "Advanced" button.

### [image: screenshot of Advanced button in Firefox options]

Change "Fallback Text Encoding" to "Central European, ISO"

[image: screenshot of Text Encoding options]

Comment: I tried this but its still not working

Comment: Sorry, perhaps try one of the other encoding options...Central European worked for me but a different one will work for you...

Comment: Missed a word: *Perhaps* a different one will work for you.